# Manipulate form between submission and validation

Tags: php, symfony

Using Symfony2 for a little while now, I ran into a problem on my current development : I need to edit the data sent by a form **before** it gets validated. Here's the situation :

- My form contains two important fields : "name" and "domain".
- "domain" refers to an entity, which has a property "domain_name".

Now, imagine "name" is set to "mywebsite" (using the form), and that the domain is set to "mydomain.com" (entity field selecting domains in a database) :

- form[name] : "mywebsite"
- form[domain] : Object (domain_name => "mydomain.com")

What I want to achieve is to change the value of the "name" field according to the selected domain. I want to append "domain_name" to "name", in order to get :

- form[name] : "mywebsite.mydomain.com"
- form[domain] : Object (domain_name => "mydomain.com")

I found 2 solutions but they don't seem to fit the situation :

- Data transformers. Seems to work on one field only, however, in order to edit "name", I need to access the "domain" entity from the form, which is not available in the Data Transformer class. What I may be looking for is a way to apply a data transformer on the whole form (but I didn't find a way to do this...)
- Form events. This will edit the "name" field **before** submission, but I want my modifications to happen after (this way, the user cannot alter them).

Is there a solution I've missed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify submitted data in `form.PRE_BIND` event. This event occurs then you call `$form->bind($request)` in controller. How to add [event subscriber](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#adding-an-event-subscriber-to-a-form-class) to form. Keep in mind that you have to deal with bare data that is not converted to entities etc.

Applying Data Transformer to entire form very easy - just dont specify field. For example

```
$builder
    ->add('name', 'text')
    ->add('domain', 'entity')
    ->addModelTransformer($transformer);
```

vs

```
// add a normal text field, but add your transformer to it
$builder->add(
    $builder->create('name', 'text')
        ->addModelTransformer($transformer)
);
```

Comment: I'll try using the PRE_BIND event. Could you tell me more about using a transformer on the whole form ? I don't see how I can access my form data in the transform() method. What's passed to the method in this case ?

Comment: You can read about data transformers here http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html. `transform` method convert Data Object to something that you past to html. `reverseTransform` method will do it  
vice versa.

Comment: I've been trying my best with transformers, but they're not what I really need in this particular case. Concerning form events, PRE_BIND is now deprecated, and PRE/POST_SUBMIT are either happening too soon/late. Even though those options are solutions, I decided to go for a custom Constraint applied to my final entity, of which the validator proceeds to the change, and runs unicity checks. Thanks for your help, solved it :)

Comment: Nice one! Glad to help